# Retrieve Intron splicings from Gene NCBI

Tags: python-3.6, biopython

I would like to retrieve the intron sequences of some genes (e.g https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/X62462.1).

I can get it with Nucleotide database for some of the genes, but some of them only appear on Gene database from NCBI. To do so, I am using Biopython.

Here a piece of code to retrieve intron from nucleotide database.

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import SeqIO, Entrez
count = 4 # Number of entries to see
genes = ["estrogen receptor"]

shortname = genes[0] 

Entrez.email = "email@gmail.com"
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term="Human[Orgn] AND "+shortname+"[GENE] AND biomol_genomic[PROP] AND nucleotide_protein[Filter]", idtype="acc", retmax=count)
record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()
```

With this part I check which entry I want:

```
print("Entries:", record["Count"])
seq_records=[]
for i in range(len(record["IdList"])):
    idname = record["IdList"][i]
    with Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", rettype="gb", retmode="text", id=idname) as handle:
        seq_record = SeqIO.read(handle, "gb")
        seq_records.append(seq_record)
        print(i, "--", seq_record.description, seq_record.id)
```

Entries: 1
0 -- H.sapiens 5' flanking region for estrogen receptor (breast) gene X62462.1

And now I retrieve the introns sequences for this gene:

```
id_chosen = 0
intron = [f for f in seq_records[id_chosen].features if f.type == "intron"]
x=1
for start, end in [(e.location.start.position, e.location.end.position ) for e in intron]:
        print(">>>",seq_record.id, "Intron:",x, start+1, end, ",len:",len(seq_record.seq[start:end]))
        x += 1
        print(seq_record.seq[start:end], "\n")
```

Output: >X62462.1 Intron: 1 911 2933 ,len: 2023
GTAGGCTTGTTTTGATTTCTCTCTCTGTAGCTTTAGCATTTTGAGAAAGCAACTTACCTTTCTGGCTAGTGTCTGTATCCTAGCAGGGAGATGAGGATTGCTGTTCTCCATGG......

In this case there is only one intron.

So my question is...how to do it with a gene that has several intron splicing and appears in the Gene database? How can I access to those features?

Example: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/374

[image: Screenshot of the Introns to retrieve]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a way to get the data you were looking for?

Comment: No, I just did it manually. I'm also taking a look to pyensembl package. But I'm having issues downloading the genome directly from python as well as recognizing the genome file (downloaded manually too) required to make it works.